# Redirect with data

Tags: go, go-gin

After successful create `user` Model (for example) I need to redirect request to... for example `root` page. But I wanna send message for ex. "User has been created!".

i can redirect with:

```
c.Redirect(http.StatusCreated, "/")
```

but how I can add message?

I tried (guess it was bad idea)

```
c.Set("message": "Message")
```

and in root page

```
s.MustGet("message")
```

but if `root` page loads without payload `message` it complain with `panic`.

Pls suggest best way for redirection with data.

**EDIT**

Unfortunately `c.Set()` doesn't work, guess it's because of `redirect`.

Maybe some one suggest any tip to send data to redirect?

Answer (score 1):

You can always call [`c.GetString("message")`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.GetString) instead of `c.MustGet("message")`

[`MustGet`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.MustGet) panics if the key does not exist as opposed to [`Get`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Get) which lets you handle existence of key and `Get` sounds more appropriate for your use-case

Answer (score 0):

For case with `Redirect` it is impossible send data in requests. So in this case uses `Session`.

According to [DOCUMENTATION](https://github.com/gin-contrib/sessions)

```
r := gin.Default()
store := cookie.NewStore([]byte("secret"))
r.Use(sessions.Sessions("mysession", store))
session.Set("message", "Oh-ho!")
session.Save()
```